# C# How to Update Visual Studio 2107 xxx.exe.config binding at runtime?

Tags: c#, web, service, visual-studio-2017, app-config

A xxx.exe.config file is created when I compile my C# web service code.  However, I want to modify one of the bindings at run time.  An example of the xxx.exe.config file generated by Visual Studio is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService"
                         messageEncoding="Mtom" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I want to add some parameters at run time to the binding named "BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" that are equivalent to manually coding:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService"                             
              messageEncoding="Mtom"
              maxBufferSize="5000000"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648"
              transferMode="Streamed" />
```

I think the C# code to define the parameter settings looks like:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding("BasicHttpBinding_ContentService");
myBinding.MaxBufferSize = 5000000;
myBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483648;
myBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
```

But I can't find a C# example (that works) that applies 'myBinding' to my Visual Studio .config file.  The samples I do find reference classes like ServiceHost and ServiceClient that are undefined in my environment.

Note - I am using .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I change quite alot of service endpoint on the fly but never use the config. I bind the webreference once then call it by code so i can change properties on the fly. Here's a very compact sample showing one that actually works

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http:\\example.com\MyService\Service.svc");

// MyService is the service object name that is in the web reference
var svc = new MyService.Service(binding, endpoint);

var clientData = svc.GetClientData("SomeClientName");
```

Comment: I am using a web service provided by a third party with 'minimal' documentation.  Your example made me examine the overloads associated with the service and I found one that accepted BasicHttpBinding and EndpointAddress, which worked!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and let me know...

```
NTEGRAWSSOAPClient _wsProtheus = null; // NTEGRAWSSOAPClient is a SOAP client class generated by vs2017 on register webservice

var endpointConfiguration = NTEGRAWSSOAPClient.EndpointConfiguration.INTEGRAWSSOAP; //INTEGRAWSSOAP is a ConfigurationName of service

_wsProtheus = new NTEGRAWSSOAPClient(endpointConfiguration,new EndpointAddress("http://new address?wsdl", new SpnEndpointIdentity("your identi")));

BasicHttpBinding bind = (BasicHttpBinding)_wsProtheus.Endpoint.Binding;

bind.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00:00");
bind.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00:00");
bind.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00:00");
bind.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00:00");
bind.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
bind.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
bind.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

bind.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
bind.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
bind.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
bind.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
bind.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;

bind.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
```

Comment: Your example makes sense.  It was helpful to contrast your method with @Franck 's suggestion.  In my case I am using a service provided by a third-party that didn't provide the same functionality that you used.